# how to compare strings with for in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void) {
    char* a = "asdf";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
        if(a[i] == "s"){
            printf("%c", a[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think this print "s" but it doesn't print anything what's the problem?

Comment: `if(a[i] == 's')`. Single quote for a character. Double quotes for string literals.

Comment: Does your compiler show some warning when you compare a `char` with a `char*` in that condition?

Answer (score 0):

In your example type of `"s"` is a `char *`, so your comparison is between a `char` and a `char *`. You have to use `'s'`, this type is a `char`.

To understand the difference try : `printf("|%c|\n", "s");` and `printf("|%c|\n", 's');`